# Serious Problem with newtxmath, newtxtext

Tags: newtxmath

I am trying to load `newtxmath` and `newtxtext` in my work and it is bringing `\DeclareRobustCommand{\sustyle}{%` error.

I removed `amssymb` and loaded only `newtxmath` and `newtxtext`, it brought `\Bbbk` is already defined.

I then added `\let\Bbbk\relax`, it didn't show any effect, it still showed `\Bbbk` is already defined no matter the position I put `\let\Bbbk\relax`.

This is my code

```
\let\Bbbk\relax
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\let\openbox\undefined
```

It is really giving me headache as I have tried every possible combination.

This is my full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\let\Bbbk\relax
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\let\openbox\undefined
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{phfthm}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{currency}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\newcommand{\lra}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\llra}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\call}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\inl}{\textup}
\def\contentsname{\textbf{CONTENTS}}
\newcommand{\sbs}{\subset}
\begin{document}

Body

\end{document}
```

This is the full error code

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.261 ...ol{\Bbbk}           {\mathord}{AMSb}{"7C}
```

and

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.93 \DeclareRobustCommand
                          {\sustyle}{%
?
```

Comment: Post a small example document that reproduces the error (starting with `\documentclass` and containing `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) and ideally also your `.log` file, so we can check your package versions.

Comment: you have not shown your input nor shown what error message you got. that makes it impossible to help

Comment: I will post that now.

Comment: Please check my post again and kindly help me from this fatal problem.

Comment: answered thanks, note that essentially nothing in the original post was related to the error as it did not mention phfthm, that's why we always ask for examples.

Comment: I removed it but still giving me this error: ! Font T1/ntxtlf/m/sl/10.95=ntx-Italic-tlf-th-t1 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metri
c (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax

Comment: I ran the following code Sir: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{phfthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

Comment: that is a separate issue, the document you posted will run without error if you move the phfthm package.  You do not appear to have the newtx fonts installed correctly, I use texlive but you should be able to update newtx in the miktex console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135066/discussion-between-abdulhafeez-ayinde-abdulsalam-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: One of the issues here seems to be with `textcomp`, which you no longer need to load. Its commands have been merged into the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Do you *really* use all those packages?

In this case

```
\usepackage{phfthm}
```

is trying to force amsfonts to redefine \Bbbk so genrates an error, commnting out that line makes the issue go.

If you really need the package load it before newtxmath since you want the tx font versions.

Answer (score 2):

`phfthm` would seem to be the culprit; it itself loads `amsthm` and `amsmath` packages, so you don't need to load those as well; so long as you load it before the `newtx*` packages, things go OK, at least for me:

No need to undefine `\Bbbk` or `\openbox`.

(Edit: Darn it, scooped again!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{phfthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{currency}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}
\newcommand{\lra}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\llra}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\call}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\inl}{\textup}
\def\contentsname{\textbf{CONTENTS}}
\newcommand{\sbs}{\subset}

\begin{document}

Body $x = y$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That gave this error pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax

Comment: Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\ABU QOTAADA ASSALAFY\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `ntx-Italic-tlf-th-.cfg'



hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)




Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

Comment: Do you get those problems when you run this sample document, or only when you make the corresponding changes to your longer document? I can't diagnose a problem I can't reproduce. I'm using TeXlive, not MikTeX.

Comment: I copied what you wrote there I didn't make any changes and that was the error.

Comment: @AbdulhafeezAyindeAbdulsalam that just means you don't have the newtx fonts correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check MikTeX console.

Comment: I think MikTeX 2.9 is a few years old by now; you might consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: Won't it rid me off my already installed packages?

Comment: As I said, I'm not a MikTeX user, so I'm not sure how upgrades work, but even if it does, you can reinstall them. Don't you want the newest versions anyway? Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It's better first to reorder your preamble.

1. `textcomp` should no longer be loaded
2. You probably load `float` for `[H]`. Don't.
3. `hyperref` should be loaded just once and last.
4. Once you state `\theoremstyle{definition}`, it continues to act until countermanded by another `\theoremstyle` declaration.
5. `\def\contentsname{\textbf{CONTENTS}}` is wrong for a couple of reasons: you don't want `\textbf` to begin with and it should be `\renewcommand`.

Finally, `phfthm` should be more cooperative towards other packages, but it seems that loading it before `newtxmath` solves the issues of duplicate commands. However, you should add the

```
qedsymbolblacksquare=false
```

option, because you don't want that `amssymb` is loaded, as `newtxmath` provides the symbols by itself. If you really want the black square for the QED symbol, issue

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
```

in the “settings” section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[qedsymbolblacksquare=false]{phfthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{currency}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

%%% theorems
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\newtheorem*{sol}{Solution}

%%% commands
\newcommand{\lra}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\llra}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\call}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\inl}{\textup}
\newcommand{\sbs}{\subset}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

%%% settings
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

%%% metadata
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

Body

\begin{proof}
OK
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I copied your code and still got: ! Font T1/ntxtlf/m/sl/10.95=ntx-Italic-tlf-th-t1 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metri
c (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.124 \end{ex}

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but please I copied your edit of my code and it still gave that error, kindly assist further.

Comment: @AbdulhafeezAyindeAbdulsalam Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Will I lose all of my already downloaded packages?

Comment: @AbdulhafeezAyindeAbdulsalam No, if you properly installed them